# I need to convert to a wave file

Tags: python, audio

Here is my work as yet.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plot
import numpy as num

def xr(start, stop, step):
    while start < stop:
        yield start
        start = start + step

wavef = lambda x: num.sin(x)/x

t0 = [wavef(x) for x in xr(5.0,200.0,0.1) if x is not 0]

plot.plot(t0)
plot.show()
```

Comment: please elaborate what exactly do you want to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python has a **wave** module [wave — Read and write WAV files](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html) .

An example of how to use it to write function data to a wav file is given here,
[Create a synthetic 'sine wave' wave file](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/code/263775#post1144145) and [How to make a simple .wav file with Python](http://codingmess.blogspot.com/2008/07/how-to-make-simple-wav-file-with-python.html).

You could also use [Audiolab](http://cournape.github.com/audiolab/) .

As you are already using numpy, you could use [numpy.linspace](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linspace.html) or [numpy.arange](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) instead of your xr function. Something like,

```
x = num.arange( 5.0, 200.0, 0.1 )
wavef = num.sin(x)/x
```